# Share files wirelessly - Homegroup for Win7 and Win10 pcs

Tags: wireless-networking, shared-hosting

I want to share data between two PCs wirelessly instead of having to use an external disk drive.

The best option from what I have found so far is to create a homegroup. (In case I am wrong, I would like to see other options in titles).

I tried to create a homegroup in the Win7 PC and then I tried to join in the Win10 PC but it said it had not found any homegroup.

I tried to create the homegroup in the Win10 PC and then I tried to join from the Win7 PC but it took too long after I added the password and failed with the message : Windows cannot set up a homegroup on this computer.

I checked the network settings and everything should be fine. I think it is a problem with my laptop (Win7) because it has some issues lately. For example, when I put an external drive (USB) I have to assign it to a letter manually on CMD.

If that is the case, I would like to see another option. If there is an option to share files no matter what the OS is (for example linux), that would be great.

Comment: Have you attempted at setting up a file share on one of the Windows systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a SMB server, that should work on both windows and linux. Then you can host the files on the respective machines and just download them on the other one.

Another option would be to use FTP.

Comment: Do we have any article related to a FTP set up that worked?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but you can give this a go: http://www.howtogeek.com/140352/how-to-host-an-ftp-server-on-windows-with-filezilla/ It shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

create a hotspot with one computer and connect as a client with another. turn firewall off and make sure that both computers have homegroup services running. create a home group on one pc and look for it with another. use wireshark to check which computer is not advertising a homegroup anyway. or maybe it is but the other does not see it somehow.